# Are dark energy and zero-point energy the same thing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

According to Quantum Mechanics is it possible that the famous ["dark energy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy) and ["zero-point energy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy) are the same thing that drives the accelerated expansion of the universe or maybe related to each other?

Comment: Possibly relevant: Jaffe, The Casimir Effect and the Quantum Vacuum, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0503158 ; Martin, Everything You Always Wanted To Know About The Cosmological Constant Problem (But Were Afraid To Ask), http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3365

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75529/

Answer (score 1):

Nobody knows. There are multiple explanations for dark energy that haven't been eliminated. One of the explanations that hasn't been eliminated is zero point energy:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3365.

Another possible explanation is that the alleged expansion is actually a result of neglecting the effects of inhomogeneities on averaging:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3787.