# Does this paper falsify the vacuum energy?

Tags: cosmology, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

If Dark Energy is falsified by this paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.04597, does that mean the vacuum energy is also falsified?

Comment: What's the connection between vacuum energy and dark energy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem The cosmological constant is supposedly the energy inherent in the vacuum and is one leading candidate for dark energy, except that vacuum energy is predicted to be 120 orders of magnitude or so too large for the cosmological constant. I have a solution to that discrepancy under peer review right now. But if Dark Energy is falsified, I'm worried my work will have been falsified prior to peer review being completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dark energy and zero-point energy the same thing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76468/are-dark-energy-and-zero-point-energy-the-same-thing)