# What form of energy is released in $E = mc^2$?

Tags: mass-energy

In the famous mass energy equivalence $ E = mc^2$ whenever any form of mass, lets say [mass defect](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mass+defect) in nuclear reactions or any other example of mass is converted to Energy, the released energy is in what form ? Heat ? Light ? Other ?

Comment: This is screaming for "Fascinating, captain: a new form of .... pure energy!"

Comment: @ Carl : certainly did not intend to ask in a way that you interpreted ! I just did not get a clear answer on google, hence asked here.

Comment: Energy is what energy does.

Answer (score 1):

See [Can we make usable energy from subnuclear particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91951/can-we-make-usable-energy-from-subnuclear-particles) for a related discussion. The energy is released both as the kinetic energy of the reaction products and as (usually gamma ray) photons.

Comment: Every time ? All cases ? NO exception ?

Comment: What other kinds *could* they be?