# Are there any real ways at least in theory to manipulate quantum vacuum for propulsion or energy generation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, energy-conservation, vacuum

https://patents.google.com/patent/US10144532B2/en

US Navy was granted a patent for polarised vacuum propulsion using microwave radiation and high em energy resonating cavities.
It seems to be a polarasible vacuum theory analog of alcubierre drive.

How far fetched are such ideas and is there any other way to pertrube vacuum modes like Casmir effect that could have potential application?

The point is why would rapidly spinning charges produces disturbances in vacuum as specified in the article?

Comment: I don't know that patent but there are many incorrect ideas about radiation reaction out there in patent land. An important consideration is that quantum (and classical) field theory respects 4-momentum conservation in flat spacetime, so an isolated system cannot accelerate itself without ejecting momentum and therefore energy too.

Comment: This is not modeled on flat spacetime in this sense. Polarisable vacuum is a model for gravity and is in some ways analogous to relativity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can energy be taken out of the QFT vacuum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11800/)