# Higgs field existence and zero energy

Tags: energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, universe, higgs

If the Higgs field permeates all space, why some claim, that total universe energy equals (or is very close to) zero?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23385/2451

Answer (score 1):

Because space is very, very flat. Even if we don't understand how the fields and masses balance out, simple observation tells us in the long haul there's not much gravitational curvature -- and that means that overall, the universe averages out to zero.

Comment: Thanks my friend. However I read in some books (or articles), that we do not have exact zero, it is close to zero. Same with respect to flatness. Anyway interesting and not easy to understand. Probably same may apply to ZPE (as meaningless against huge flatness)? Thanks for being here.