# Where does all the energy in the universe come from?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, universe, big-bang

The principle of conservation of energy says that all energy in a system will remain the same. It can just be transformed.

The universe contains a huge amount of energy, but where did it come from? 
I know there isn't that ONE answer, but I'm curious as to what the thoughts and theories about this question are.

Comment: there are many duplicates. ie [Is it possible all matter in the universe emerges from nothing?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39595/) . Look at *Related* column on the right page

Comment: One theory is that the universe cycles between expansion and collapsing. The energy from the Big Bang could have been a bounce from a Big Crunch.