Noether's Theorem in relativistic cosmologies
Is Noether's Theorem valid within the context of relativistic cosmology? If not, does this mean that the universe does not conserve energy on cosmological time and distance scales?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40983/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35431/2451 More on energy conservation in relativistic cosmology.

I don't think this is a duplicate since it specifically asks about Noether's theorem.

Noether's theorem is valid for any system that can be described by an action, so it's valid for any solution to Einstein's equations. I guess you're asking whether time shift symmetry applies to the universe i.e. does the FLRW metric have a timelike Killing vector?

If so this is related to, and possibly a duplicate of, How do we know that the actual universe has no Killing vector fields?.

See also Time-like Killing vector in FRW metric?.


Strictly speaking Noether's Theorem is by itself always valid since it is a proven mathematical theorem, which relies on an action formulation and a symmetry. 2. More importantly, in the context of relativistic cosmology, there is no global time-translation symmetry nor a mathematically well-defined notion of gravitational energy.


@Qmechanic is there local time-translation symmetry on size scales ~the solar system? ditto for a well-defined notion of gravitational energy?

@niels nielsen. By the word local I assume you are not thinking of a local gauge symmetry, but rather a sufficiently small system with an appropriate asymptotic reference metric, such as e.g. a galaxy, a solar system or a binary star. If so, we can in principle assign a gravitational energy to the system. It might not be conserved due to e.g. gravitational radiation or ejections, i.e. the system may not stay localized.

@Qmechanic, Yes that's it exactly, thanks. -NN
