# The universe could have created itself?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, energy-conservation, big-bang

So in this Youtube video http://youtu.be/ZjaaSUHG7Xo
The guy says, around 6:15, that the total energy of the universe is zero because of gravitational potential (or something like that i dont understand completely which is why I'm asking this question) so since the totally energy of the universe is zero, the law of conservation would not have been violated by the universe coming into existence at the big bang. I heard about a similar argument made in one of Stephen Hawking's books.  Could someone explain the idea to me in its fullness? Thanks. And if you disagree with the idea that the universe could have created itself, hopefully this goes without saying in a forum like this, please no responses based on religious dogma.

Comment: "please no responses based on religious dogma" That does indeed go without saying.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/

Comment: *"the law of conservation would not have been violated by the universe coming into existence at the big bang"*  Does the law of [energy] conservation exist *apart* from the Universe?