# A universe from nothing

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, universe

The more time you spending in measuring your experiment (thus standard deviation will become smaller) the more precisely you will measure energy of this system....
energy time uncertainly principle implies this....
and in most systems (i have seen,or may be all systems )
the lowest possible energy is ground state energy, this energy cannot be removable..
for example in a infinit square well ..
Then how can ''universe from nothing''
i would say sentence makes sense?
if there is uncertainly how there is something like nothing...
if minimum energy possible is ground state energy..how nothing(no energy exist)???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Total energy of the Universe](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/)

Answer (score -1):

What is "nothing"? Can somebody please get this experimentalist a couple of liters of "nothing", so that he can do some basic physical measurements on "nothing"?

Moreover, can someone point me to a paper where the total energy of the universe has been measured experimentally?

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: @BenCrowell: What doesn't address the question? The fact that physics can not deal with "nothing"? Please. I know that you know better than that. And it's not a scientific fact that nobody has ever measured the energy of the universe? I have merely wrapped these two obvious statements into Socratic questions.

Comment: Replace "nothing" with "0", the same doubt happend in history. we can test 0, can stay at 0,  we can have a liter of zeros, because that is just another way to say "we don't have that liter of things", we can keep that state. It's a interesting question.

Our universe space curvature is 0, that is a good experiment example.