# Determining zero energy from $k=0$?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, universe, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm curious as to the equations necessary for finding a total energy of 0 (or, I suppose, the energy density of empty space due to quantum fluctuations) in a flat Friedmann universe such as ours.

The FLRW metric is as follows:

$
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Sigma}^2 = \frac{\mathrm{d}r^2}{1-k r^2} + r^2 \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Omega}^2
$

And solving the formula the formula:
$$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Sigma}^2 = \mathrm{d}r^2 + S_k(r)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Omega}^2$$
For a $S_k(r)$ where $k=0$ gives us $r$. Adding in the scale factor, we get a simplified equation:
$$d^2(t) = a^2(t)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$$
But this has nothing to do with the energy of the system, only the curverature and the distance between points at a given time $t$. I'd like to understand why a flat universe has a cumulative energy of zero in a mathematical equation. I understand that the gravitational potential energy is the counteractive energy to matter, but I'm looking for a mathematical equation that shows this and I'm wondering if it is truly absolute zero, since the $\text{Uncertainty Principle}$ tells us zero is impossible for an oscillating system:
$$
\Delta E\cdot \Delta t \ge {\hbar\over 2}
$$

Comment: to get a vacuum density different than zero you need either a cosmological constant or some quantum field equivalent to it (but we do not have a quantum theory of gravitation yet).

Comment: Ahh, thank you. However, I'm looking for an equation (unfinished or currently unsolvable is perfectly fine) that would seemingly describe our Universe's total energy for a $K$ value of $0$.

Comment: I am not sure to understand if you want the energy density of the vacuum or the total energy density, which includes the matter/energy present in the universe.

Comment: both are actually parameters of the Friedman equations, so you do not "calculate" them, you give them values to solve your model (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations)

Comment: both values determine if the solution results in an expanding, static, or expanding universe

Comment: I'm talking of the total energy density of the universe.

Comment: you do not calculate either of them, as I said (they could have any values given by you on the Friedman equations), please check the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total energy of the universe is a vexed issue since different commentators have different views about what the concept means. See the question [Total energy of the Universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/total-energy-of-the-universe) for a sampling of the various viewpoints. If you Google for [zero energy universe](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=zero%20energy%20universe) you'll find several papers purporting to show that the total energy is zero. However since their results depend on the assumptions they make at the start treat their conclusions with care - because a paper appears on the Arxiv does not necessarily make it authoritative.

You might want to read [Phil Gibbs' views on the subject](http://blog.vixra.org/2010/08/17/energy-is-conserved-in-cosmology/), though note that another prominent member of this site, Luboš Motl, [heartily disagrees](http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/why-and-how-energy-is-not-conserved-in.html).