# Universe from nothing

Tags: cosmology

Does this video make sense?

[The Simple Math for a Universe from Nothing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Yoo41URt-E)

I mean, can I really explain a "universe from nothing" is this simple manner?

Comment: Note:i am an undergraduate student

Comment: "Nothing" in science (physics) means the quantum vacuum and not the "absence of anything", as far as I know.

Comment: See [Total energy of the Universe](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/total-energy-of-the-universe). This is essentially a duplicate of your question. The video is pointless because you can't describe the universe without general relativity.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate, but beyond that it's not even asking anything as currently written. Questions need to be self-contained so that you don't need external resources to understand what they're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is metaphysics, instead of God creating the universe , it has Nature creating the universe, and hand waves mathematical possibilities to justify this metaphysical premise.

Some inconsistency in the end when using Newtons gravitational equation and assuming the masses zero, he says that the distance is zero too, but the distance between two nonexistent masses is undefined, not zero.

In a sense also it is a fall back to the [platonic ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_idealism) of philosophy , when seen as  "mathematics exists and forces form" .

Avoiding the word "creation" gets closer to physics theories which at the moment are open ended as to the beginning of our universe, i.e. there are various proposals which you may study if you continue in physics. As the beginning of the universe requires a unification of forces and quantization of gravity this is a research frontier. There may be much more interesting mathematics after all, than simple equations. They might tell us how the "choice" was made, so more interesting metaphysics :).

Comment: I'm hoping that one day we'll find messages encoded in the cosmic background radiation which read
1. "The choice is made!"
2. "I tried to think of the most harmless thing. Something I loved from my childhood. Something that could never, ever possibly destroy us. Mr. Stay Puft."