# Why does a universe with total positive energy eventually collapse in a crunch?

Tags: universe, cosmological-inflation

While reading about negative energy in the following Wikipedia page, I came across a statement that, if in a universe positive energy dominates, it will eventually collapse upon itself in a crunch.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_energy

I am unable to understand why. If the total energy is positive, and we know that the gravitational energy is negative, then the energy of expansion of the universe will be more positive than the total energy of the universe. Doesn't this mean that the universe will keep expanding?

Comment: There is no such thing as the total energy of the universe. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/total-energy-of-the-universe .