# How was energy created in the first place?

Tags: energy, cosmology, universe, big-bang

I've been really curious about how energy was created in the first place. Does anyone have any possible theories that they beleive caused energy to exist in the first place?

Comment: Related question: [Is the total energy of the universe zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/is-the-total-energy-of-the-universe-zero)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be meaningful to talk about the total energy of the universe, and, if it is, some physicists think it is probably [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-energy_universe). We have no evidence that any net energy has gotten “created”.