# The gravitational field of all the distant mass exactly cancels the positive mass-energy in the universe. Why do they think so?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, energy-conservation, universe

It is often said that the gravitational field has negative energy, and that this negative gravitational energy of all the distant mass exactly cancels the positive mass-energy in the universe.

Why do we think they exactly balance?

A more formal (preferably) mathematical) explanation would be preferred, instead of analogies.

thank you

Comment: What do you mean "it is often said"? This sounds like the [zero-energy universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-energy_universe) model, which is not exactly universally accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure where you read this. Probably they are referring to the 'effective stress-energy tensor'=$T_{ab}-\frac{1}{\kappa}G_{ab}=0$ (from Einstein's field equation). Einstein tensor $G_{ab}$ is not the stress energy tensor for gravity. Total energy need not be conserved in a generic case. I'll probably post an answer sometime later

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Energy is the ability of a system to perform work on another system. What is that "other system" that the universe is supposed to perform work on? If there is no such system, then what is the phrase "energy of the universe" supposed to mean?

Comment: > What do you mean "it is often said"? This sounds like the zero-energy universe model,   which is not exactly universally accepted.