# When two photons annihilate each other through destructive interference, where does the energy go?

Tags: visible-light, photons, interference

When two photons annihilate each other through destructive interference, where does the energy go?

Perhaps this is only answered by ‘wave type’ questions and answers? Does the conservation of energy get violated?

Comment: Also [Energy conservation and interference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7707/energy-conservation-and-interference)

Comment: The question is built on a misunderstanding. Interference is not a QFT operation. Destructive interference is not annihilation.

Comment: Photons don't "annihilate" each other. The interference is between the wave functions that predict where the photons are likely to go.