# Is conservation of energy a given?

Tags: energy-conservation

Where does all the energy to make mass come from if the mass in the past and the future is still there. Aswell as here.

Comment: This may help - [Energy conservation and General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306838/37364)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19216/2451 and libks therein.

Comment: *the mass in the past and the future is still there* Mass *isn’t* conserved, at least not in the sense of the total mass of individual particles. For example, a massive electron and a massive positron can annihilate to two photons, neither of which has any mass.

Comment: I get that. It's all mostly stored energy contained by the fundamental particals strength of connection to the Higgs field. Using the strong force.

Comment: How does mass stretch spacetime before spacetime stretches to accommodate the necessary interactions between the element fields and the Higgs field,  to contain the energy in an attom that gives it its mass.